# AWS IoT Jobs and OTA Updates when device is in sleep mode

Tags: aws-iot, freertos, ota, aws-iot-core

What happens if I send an OTA Update and the device is in deep sleep mode? It wakes up immediately, waits for the next wake up and then runs automatically or it does not run at all on it?

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on what your device is, how "deep sleep" and wakeup from it is implemented in this device and how it's connected to Internet.

Option 1: no. Most likely the networking hardware is switched off to save power and (if it's really deep sleep) the micro's core is also suspended (i.e. it doesn't execute code). In this state the device couldn't receive any messages from the network.

Option 2: depends on what the device does when it wakes up. If it connects to Internet and connects to AWS IoT and receives the command, then probably yes. This functionality is up to the developer of embedded firmware to design and implement. Otherwise no.